# ASP.net: ReportViewer not displaying (parameters from dynamically created textboxes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, report, reportserver

I have an existing code that displays a reportserver RDL report in a reportviewer.  I prompt the user for inputs and those are then passed as parameters to a store procedure in Sql Server.

The report generates properly as proof of concept with hard-coded number of textboxes, but obviously not all reports will have the same number of parameters.  So here is my working code and the screenshot:

[Working Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAlY1.png)

ASP.NET

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Trace="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reports.aspx.cs" Inherits="FormsAuthAd.Reports" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="reports-body">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Reports</title>
    <link href="../css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="params-container container">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server" placeholder="From Date" class="input-fields"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnd" runat="server" placeholder="To Date" class="input-fields"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBrand" runat="server" placeholder="Brand" class="input-fields"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSeason" runat="server" placeholder="Season" class="input-fields"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComp" runat="server" placeholder="Company" class="input-fields"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoc" runat="server" placeholder="Location" class="input-fields"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLine" runat="server" placeholder="Line" class="input-fields"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Generate"  class="input-fields"/>
    </div>
    <div class="rpt-container container">
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptVwr" runat="server" CssClass="rpt-viewer"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
private void showReport()
{
    rptVwr.Reset();
        DataTable dt = GetData(txtStart.Text, txtEnd.Text, txtBrand.Text, txtSeason.Text, txtComp.Text, txtLoc.Text);
        rptVwr.Visible = true;
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dt);
        rptVwr.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        rptVwr.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../ReportServer/StockExport.rdl";

        ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[]
        {
        new ReportParameter("StartDate",txtStart.Text),
                new ReportParameter("EndDate",txtEnd.Text),
                new ReportParameter("Brand",txtBrand.Text),
                new ReportParameter("Season",txtSeason.Text),
                new ReportParameter("Company",txtComp.Text),
                new ReportParameter("Store",txtLoc.Text),
        };
        rptVwr.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
        rptVwr.LocalReport.Refresh();
}

private DataTable GetData(string fromDate, string toDate, string brandCode, string seasonCode, string compCode, string locCode)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["ReportServerConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_valueEntryStock", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fromDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = toDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Season", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = seasonCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Brand", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = brandCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = compCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Store", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = locCode;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adp.Fill(dt);
    }
        return dt;

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showReport();
}
```

Obviously, I did not want a hard-coded number of textboxes so I tweaked my code to dynamically add textboxes on page load based on a table in Sql Server.Here is my existing code and screenshot:

[Page after submitting parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6F7z.png)

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [FieldNum],[FieldName],[AspId],[SqlParameter] FROM [MIS_FieldsMaster]", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        adp.Fill(dtable);
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtable.Rows)
                        {
                            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                            tb.ID = dr["AspId"].ToString().Trim();
                            stringArray[i] = dr["SqlParameter"].ToString().Trim();
                            tb.Text = stringArray[i];
                            ph1.Controls.Add(tb);
                            i++;
                        }
                }
    }

}

private void showReport()
{
    rptVwr.Reset();
        DataTable dt = GetData();
        rptVwr.Visible = true;
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dt);
    rptVwr.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    rptVwr.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../ReportServer/StockExport.rdl";
        rptVwr.LocalReport.Refresh();
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int i = 0;

        string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReportServerConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_valueEntryStock", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (TextBox textBox in ph1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + stringArray[i], textBox.Text);
                    i++;
                }
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adp.Fill(dt);
    }
            return dt;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showReport();
}
```

So it does not even show me any error message so I do not really know where to look.  I debugged the new code and I believe it is retrieving the data in the stored procedure because the local variable shows rows retrieved under datatable dt.  The only thing is the report does not show in the reportViewer.  It does not even show report toolbars.

[Row retrieved from datatable dt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dguaC.png)

I would greatly appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason for the report not displaying in the reportviewer.

It seems that I still need to add the parameters and set it to the reportviewer, like in my first working code:

```
ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[]
{
new ReportParameter("StartDate",txtStart.Text),
        new ReportParameter("EndDate",txtEnd.Text),
        new ReportParameter("Brand",txtBrand.Text),
        new ReportParameter("Season",txtSeason.Text),
        new ReportParameter("Company",txtComp.Text),
        new ReportParameter("Store",txtLoc.Text),
};
rptVwr.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
```

Obviously =, it still needs to be dynamic so here is the code that I used:

```
List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
int i = 0;

foreach (TextBox textBox in ph1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    paramList.Add(new ReportParameter(stringArray[i], textBox.Text));
    i++;
}
rptVwr.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList);
```

Now, I am able to generate the dynamic textboxes and at the same time pass the values in those textboxes to my sql server stored procedure and finally generate and display the report based on the same textboxes.

I would consider this solved, but I just have a niggling question in my head:

Why didn't my code work when it is exactly the same (at least logically if not syntactically) as the code in the youtube example that I took: [Two way to pass parameter in stored procedure and display the output in Report Viewer using C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txYnDrdO8FM)